# spilt string with 2 or more possibilites with action script 2

Tags: actionscript-2

I am trying to simplify a baseURL string with action script 2.

But I am having trouble as my base URL could have to possible begginings.

What I have so far.. Thanks to *@Will Kru*

```
.split("http://").join("").split("/")[0];
```

So if my baseURL is this... **http://www.actionscript.com/category/splitting**

Then the above code would return... **www.actionscript.com**

My next problem is, the baseURL could be in SSL mode. So the beggining of the string would be **https://**

So my question is - is there anyway to split the baseURL from the first `://` and remove what ever appears before the `://` - wether it is `http` or `https`

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
.split("://")[1].split("/")[0]
```